# Create album thumbnail like iOS 7 iPad photos app

Tags: ios, ipad

Question: Is the following strategy viable?

```
if there are at least 3 images in the album,
   create a small (i.e 45 * 45) thumbnail of 3rd to last image
if there are at least 2 images in the album,
   create a 50 * 50 thumbnail of 2nd to last image 
   overlay on 3rd to last image if there is one
if there is at least 1 image in the album,
   create a 55 * 55 thumbnail of the last image
   overlay on the result of the previous conditional
```

The overlay would make sure that 3rd to last image is a few points raised in comparison to the 2nd to last, and the same happens with 2nd to last and last image.

I have used the following code to generate thumbnails before

```
#pragma mark - Reduce Image Size
+(UIImage *)scaleImage:(UIImage *)image toSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Define 'viable'. When you've done that, the question should answer itself. Not a real question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No buddy, you're going about this all wrong. The photos app uses UICollectionView. UICollectionView itself is capable of allowing you to do this, in a way. You need to use a custom UICollectionViewLayout along with the zIndex property.

But you should start off by watching WWDC 2012 Session 205 and Session 219. The first gives you an introduction to UICollectionView and the second is a little more in depth.

Then, download https://github.com/constantineSafronov/SFAlbumApp. Look at its code, especially SFStackLayout. You will have to modify that code.